# JS errors when creating a custom grid table in magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, grid, dashboard

I use this link to create a custom grid table
https://webkul.com/blog/create-grid-edit-add-grid-row-and-installer-in-magento2/
 and after that it does not go further
[image: s]

the console gives a Javascript error, who can help? why I get the error filter.js and object.js, fromthis errors  I think my module is not working properly

[image: j]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Grid record list UI Component
 * @category  Webkul
 * @package   Webkul_Grid
 * @author    Webkul
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010-2017 Webkul Software Private Limited (https://webkul.com)
 * @license   https://store.webkul.com/license.html
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customgrid_grid_grid_listing.customgrid_grid_grid_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">customgrid_grid_grid_listing.customgrid_grid_grid_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">customgrid_grid_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Row</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/addrow</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="customgrid_grid_grid_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">customgrid_grid_grid_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">customer_data_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">customgrid_grid_grid_listing.customgrid_grid_grid_listing.grid_records_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customgrid_grid_grid_listing.customgrid_grid_grid_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">​_
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customgrid_grid_grid_listing.customgrid_grid_grid_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">customgrid_grid_grid_listing.customgrid_grid_grid_listing.grid_records_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">customgrid_grid_grid_listing.customgrid_grid_grid_listing.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <!-- Mass actions which you want to add in your grid-->
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="grid/grid/massdelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customgrid_grid_grid_listing.customgrid_grid_grid_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">customgrid_grid_grid_listing.customgrid_grid_grid_listing.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="grid_records_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">customer_data_id</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="customer">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CUSTOMER ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="subscribe" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SUBSCRIBE DATE</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="chackout" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">CustomGrid\Grid\Model\Status</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CHECKOUT PRODUCT DAY</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="add_to_cart" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ADD TO CART DAY</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
       <!-- <column name="update_time" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Update Time</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>-->
        <!-- Add Action with each row of grid and for this we will create a class Action -->
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="CustomGrid\Grid\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Action">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Add your Ui component XML, please

Comment: I updated my question